# Как узнать размеры окна в Windows 7?

Tags: windows, powershell

Как узнать размеры окна в Windows 7?

Comment: Смотря в какой среде работаете и для чего вам это нужно.

Comment: Мне хочется подтвердить предположение о том, что окно браузера больше ширины экрана. Смежный вопрос тут: [хешкод][1]
[1]http://hashcode.ru/questions/73690/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-window-outerwidth-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: Если окно браузера то это js

Comment: как вариант, можно просто померить линейкой

Comment: @vital_viza, вопрос возник как раз из-за того, что я померил ширину через js и она оказалась не такая какую ожидал. Вопрос по ссылке как раз об этом.

Comment: @Gorets, линейка не дает измерить окно выходящее за границы экрана. Если вы сдвинете окно частично за границу экрана, то как вам поможет линейка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если язык не принципиален, то:

1. получить размер экрана можно например через свойства `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` (С#, есть аналоги на С++, VB, F#);
2. или аналогичный метод `Screen.GetBounds()` (С#, аналогично есть на C++ и т.д.).
3. Для получение размера окна браузера можно взять свойство WebBrowser.Bounds

Для powershell попробуйте погуглить. Например, [вот](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/123772-how-position-powershell-window-screen.html).

P.S. Хэшкод, зачем правку то потерли?